# How to access Child class variable having same name as in Parent class and we have only get method in parent class with no setter method

Tags: java

On running below code i am getting this answer
Parent 50
Child 50
Parent 50

But I believe it should return Child 90. I am confused over this:

```
public class PolySameVar {
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
      Parent par = new Parent();
      par.getx();
      Child chld=new Child();
      chld.getx();
      Parent parchld= new Parent();
      parchld.getx();
    }
}


class Parent {
    private int x;
    Parent(){
        x=50;
    }
public void getx(){
        String className = this.getClass().getName();
        System.out.println(className+" "+this.x);
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{
    private int x;
    Child(){
        x=90;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't override variables.

Comment: Add a getter to `Child` called `getx()`, which will return the `x` value for the actual `Child` instance.